# Where Firefox extensions store data?

Tags: firefox

I want to write plugin for [GNOME Do](http://do.davebsd.com/), that will work with Firefox extensions data (for example, with [URL Alias](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8703) patterns). I have looked through files in my profile folder (~/.mozilla/firefox/.default/), but haven't found anything related.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unzipped the XPI, and it looks like the key data is stored in the [preference system](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Prefs.js_file) under the `urlalias` branch.  This is serialized to disk in the `prefs.js`. file  Each line is a single preference, so it should be pretty simple to parse (you could conceivably use Firefox's XPCOM interface, but that's probably unnecessary).